# Compare fields in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, javascript, javascript-controller

I have a lightning component which the goal of it is to open a page if some fields on the record are not null, how to compare those fields to null?
Here the component:

```
<aura:component controller="purchaseOrderComponentController"
    implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" default="a0e2000000X2I9AAAV"/>
    <aura:attribute name="purchaseOrder" type="PBSI__PBSI_Purchase_Order__c"/>   
</aura:component>
```

Here the JS controller:

```
({
    doInit : function (component, event) {
        var purchaseOrderId  = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getPurchaseOrder");
       // window.open('https://something.visual.force.com/apex/ReceivePO?id='+purchaseOrderId);
        action.setParams({
            "purchaseOrderId": purchaseOrderId
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function (response){

            component.set('v.purchaseOrder',response.getReturnValue());
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // should compare the fields to null, the fields from the apex controller
                // if they are not null then open a page, otherwise show a message.
            } 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Here the apex controller:

```
public class purchaseOrderComponentController{
  @AuraEnabled
  public static  PBSI__PBSI_Purchase_Order__c getPurchaseOrder(Id purchaseOrderId) {
    return [SELECT Id, PBSI__Delivery_Location__c, Order_Confirmation_Number__c, Has_Misc_Item__c FROM PBSI__PBSI_Purchase_Order__c where Id=:purchaseOrderId limit 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare the state variable and get it from the response object, which might be your main issue. Adjust your code as follows.

---

```
    action.setCallback(this,function (response){
        var state = response.getState(),
            purchaseOrder = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.purchaseOrder',purchaseOrder);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            if(purchaseOrder.Order_Confirmation_Number__c) { // Modify this here //
               // you would redirect here //
            } else {
              // show an error //
            }
        } 
    });
```

I'll leave you to adjust the appropriate parts from here.